# Apache Ignite: start both client and server nodes in the same JVM

Tags: ignite

Is it possible to start both client and server nodes in the same JVM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can start several nodes within one JVM. You only need to make sure that `IgniteConfiguration.getGridName()` property is unique for each node. Here is the example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ignite server = startNode("server-node");
    Ignite client = startNode("client-node");

    ...
}

private static Ignite startNode(String name) {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    cfg.setGridName(name);

    return Ignition.start(cfg);
}
```

Comment: You can use `setIgniteInstanceName` now as `setGridName` is deprecated.